# highlighting text in shell

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, highlighting

I have always been using below method to highlight background of text in shell .

```
tput smso;printf " TEXT ";tput rmso;
```

How can I achieve the same thing without using `tput`( I mean some way formatting like `\e[0m` for colors in printf) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412761/using-colors-with-printf

Comment: I am looking for code for highlighting text similar to the ones used for coloring.This link talks about only colors.

Comment: well, you need to know the correct escape codes and before the text you puts your coloring and after you remove. Here you have a table of the combinations: http://bitmote.com/public/ansi_4bit_color_table.png
printf works with the escapes code that you mentioned on your question.

Comment: Why would you trade a portable and somewhat readable technique for a nonportable unreadable one? If you want to save processes, maybe `p="$(tput smso)"; q="$(tput rmso)"` when you initialize, then use `print "${p}can i haz cheeseburger?${q}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escape sequences for that may be terminal specific. That's the whole point of using `tput`. tputs looks up the correct escape sequence in a database based on the value of the `$TERM` variable.

On my terminal:

```
$ tput smso | sed -n l
\033[3m$
$ tput rmso | sed -n l
\033[23m$
```

So I could do:

```
$ printf '\033[3m%s\033[23m\n' "stand out"
```

But I can't be sure that would work on other terminals.

If you don't want to call `tput` each time, you can run it once and store the output:

```
smso=$(tput smso)  rmso=$(tput rmso)
printf '%s\n' "${smso}stand out${rmso}"
```

Note that `smso` is "Start Mode Stand-Out", it is not for reverse video, though many terminals use reverse video to make text stand out. If you want reverse video, it's `tput rev` (cancelled by `tput sgr0`), if you want to set the background colour, use `tput setab 4` for ANSI colour codes (with 4 being the ANSI colour blue number).